# Authorization header is invalid -- one and only one ' ' (space) required --- in C# (S3 commands)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, authorization

I'm getting the following error while trying to set up my credentials for AWS/S3.

```
A client error (InvalidArgument) occurred when calling the ListObjects operation: Authorization header is invalid -- one and only one ' ' (space) required
```

I can't figure out why, because there are no extra spaces.  Here's my code:

```
String commands = @"set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=kkkkkkkkkkkkk";
commands += @" & set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=ssssssssssssssssss";
```

Why would I be getting this error when there's no extra spaces?  I had an issue earlier with string literals, but would that be causing this, too?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the amphersand.

```
@"set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=keykeykey set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secretsecretsecret";
```